# Migrated Joomla 1 to 2.5 and VirtueMart 1.x to 2.x and lost product images

Tags: migration, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have lost my product images.
When I check `/jupgrade/administrator/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=media` it displays the complete list of jpg's.

There is this button to `synchronize media to virtuemart` but that did not work.
the products are all there, but have no images.

I hope that I made my issue clear. Please let me know if you need additional information.

The output of the sync media button:

```
Found prior migration process, resume migration maxScriptTime 47 maxMemoryLimit 82
Synchronized 0 media for product in directory images/stories/virtuemart/product/
Synchronized 0 media for category in directory images/stories/virtuemart/category/
Synchronized 0 media for manufacturer in directory images/stories/virtuemart/manufacturer/
Synchronized 0 media for vendor in directory images/stories/virtuemart/vendor/
Synchronized 0 media for forSale in directory
Synchronized alltogether 0 files
```

crossposted http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=118898.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i remember correctly, the images are not migrated automatically, you have to manually move them from old (/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/) to new ( /images/stories/virtuemart/)directory before sync.

In virtuemart configuration (when executing sync) the images are then auto added to products.

Please check this link for more info: http://emanipur.org/blog/item/157-migrate-virtuemart-119-to-2xx-without-losing-any-data